# pip install from custom whl file in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, python-wheel

I have a Dockerfile which is trying to install a `whl` file which is located in my project using `pip`. I want to force `pip` to include my `whl` file in its searches, but it doesn't:

```
No distributions matching the version for mylibname==mylibversion
```

I tried using `build_ext` with options `-L`:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/directory/containing/whl/file/"
```

`-I`:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/directory/containing/whl/file/"
```

and `-b`:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-b/directory/containing/whl/file/"
```

But none of them worked.

**EDIT 1:**

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:2.7.9
MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
ADD myprojectdir .
RUN ls -la ${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency
RUN pip --version
RUN pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency" mypackagename-mypackageversion
WORKDIR .
CMD python --version
```

This is the output of `docker build -t myimagename .`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.096 kB
Step 1 : FROM python:2.7.9
 ---> 646fa5bbf55d
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Zeinab Abbasimazar
 ---> d08f7cb9e985
Step 2 : ADD myprojectdir .
 ---> 0e190b21a30b
Step 3 : RUN ls -la ${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency
total 1740
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff    4096 Sep  6 11:58 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff    4096 Sep  6 11:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  454253 Sep  6 11:58 mypackagename-mypackageversion-py2-none-any.whl
 ---> d069986bd3b6
Step 4 : RUN pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
 ---> ddeccc833ea2
Step 5 : RUN pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency" mypackagename-mypackageversion
Downloading/unpacking mypackagename-mypackageversion
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypackagename-mypackageversion
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for mypackagename-mypackageversion
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency" mypackagename-mypackageversion' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**EDIT2:**

The `pip install /path/to/the/whl/file.whl` completely works; but it's not what I want.

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile, your error messages...

Comment: @user2915097, I edited my question. Please review.

Comment: Can you try `pip install --no-index --find-links=${HOME}/myprojectdir/dependency mypackagename-mypackageversion` ?

Comment: Why not just `pip install /pat/to/my.whl`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, still getting `No distributions matching the version for mypackagename-mypackageversion`.

Comment: @phd, I have a list of package names:versions which I want to iterate over them and a directory contains all packages' whl files. I'm not keeping actual file names which is not under my control. I just have the knowledge that all my packages can be found there.

Comment: `pip install /path/to/*.whl`

Comment: @phd, that was great and solved everything. Would you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install all wheels without listing them explicitly:

```
pip install /path/to/*.whl
```

Comment: A caveat that the OP didn't require is the ability to install extras. This solution will not work if you need something like `pip install pkg.whl[dev]`.

Comment: @Keto In what way it doesn't work? Extras are just additional packages, if they're included in `*.whl` they will be installed; installation order is not important.

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe I meant if you want to "Install all wheels without listing them explicitly" and at the same time set extras on certain packages. You cannot glob `*.whl`.